# mysql - sort by most completed row

Tags: mysql, sorting

I am working with sort syntax for mysql db and i would like to sort the rows by completion of columns. I hope example will describe the issue:

```
id |t1 | t2 | t3 | t4
----------------------
 1 | a |  b |  c | d
 2 |   |  e |    |
 3 | f |  g |    |
 4 | h |  i | j  |
```

this is my row/column structure. As you can see, some of the fields are empty. I'd like to sort the table so the imput would look like this

```
id |t1 | t2 | t3 | t4
----------------------
 1 | a |  b |  c | d
 4 | h |  i | j  |
 3 | f |  g |    |
 2 |   |  e |    |
```

It's been sorted by number of filled (non-empty) fields. The easiest way to do this is to sort with such a query:

```
SELECT id, t1, t2, t3, t4 FROM table ORDER BY t1 DESC, t2 DESC, t3 DESC, t4 DESC
```

It works good in most of cases but look what will happen if my table looks like this:

```
id |t1 | t2 | t3 | t4
----------------------
 1 |   |  b |  c | d
 2 |   |  z |    |
```

After sorting:

```
id |t1 | t2 | t3 | t4
----------------------
 2 |   |  z |    |
 1 |   |  b |  c | d
```

Why? Because sort order is descending, and t1 column is empty (so it's ignored), and the next column is t2. It is also sorted descending ignoring rest of the columns (if they are empty).

I found similiar problem solved (i guess - not checked yet) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107081/mysql-query-order-by-most-completed-fields) but the solution looks nasty. Do you have other ideas to sort the table by number of non-empty columns?

Comment: You stumbled upon a problem and you're looking for its solution - however, even though you might find the solution to the specific problem (the one in the link you posted *is* the solution), are you certain that your feature is best solved by using the approach you mentioned here?

Comment: I agree with @N.B.  See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: This kind of problem is often symptomatic of poor normalisation. Are you sure you cannot better structure your schema?

Comment: +1 for sorting you are requestiong. But not much for the question articulation though ;) sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should sum the results of `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` for all of the relevant columns and use that as a primary sort to solve your basic problem, then impose whatever secondary sort you want.

It's unclear to me how you want to sort two rows with the same number of non-null column values, but I'll guess that you want to sort them ascending, left to right, in which case this should work for you:

(UPDATE: as eggyal pointed out, by "empty" you mean the empty string, not NULL. See updated query below):

```
SELECT id, t1, t2, t3, t4 
FROM table 
ORDER BY ((t1 = '') + (t2 = '') + (t3 = '') + (t4 = '')) ASC, 
t1 DESC, t2 DESC, t3 DESC, t4 DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

You effectively need to create a score for each record and sort on that.  I suggest testing whether each field is "empty" and taking the sum, then sorting in ascending order (so that lowest scores, i.e. records with the least empty fields, come first).

You can abuse MySQL's lack of true boolean types to create such a score as follows:

```
ORDER BY (t1 IS NULL) + (t2 IS NULL) + (t3 IS NULL) + (t4 IS NULL)
```

Or, if your "empty" fields are in fact the empty string `''` instead of `NULL`:

```
ORDER BY (t1 = '') + (t2 = '') + (t3 = '') + (t4 = '')
```

Comment: your second advice works perfectly fine for me. just curious - how to sort it in ascending order?